# Formatting the data correctly from text file using pandas Python

Tags: python, dictionary, dataframe

I have data in my .txt file

```
productname1
7,64
productname2
6,56
4.73
productname3
productname4
12.58
10.33
```

So the data is explained here. We have product name in the first name and in the 2nd line is the price. But for 2nd product name we have original product price and discounted price. Also, the prices sometimes contain '.' and ',' to represent cents. I want to format the data in the following way

```
    Product   o_price   d_price
productname1    7.64       -
productname2    6.56      4.73
productname3    -          -
productname4    12.58    10.33
```

My current approach is a bit naive but it works for 98% of the cases

```
import pandas as pd
data = {}
tempKey = []
with open("myfile.txt", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    arr_content = file.readlines()
    for val in arr_content:
        if not val[0].isdigit():# check whether Starting letter is a digit or text
            val = ' '.join(val.split()) # Remove extra spaces
            data.update({val: []}) # Adding key to the dict and initializing it with a list in which I'll populate values
            tempKey.append(val) # keeping track of the last key added because dicts are not sequential
         else:
             data[str(tempKey[-1])].append(val) # Using last added key and updating it with prices

df = pd.DataFrame(list(data.items()), columns = ['Product', 'Pricelist'])
df[['o_price', 'd_price']] = pd.DataFrame([x for x in df.Pricelist])
df = df.drop('Prices', axis=1)
```

So this technique does not work when product name starts with a digit. Any suggestions for a better approach ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression to check if the line contains only numbers and/or periods.

```
if (re.match("^[0-9\.]*$", val)):

   # This is a product price

else:

   # This is a product name
```